# More efficient way to find & tar millions of files

Tags: bash, find, tar

I've got a job running on my server at the command line prompt for a two days now:

```
find data/ -name filepattern-*2009* -exec tar uf 2009.tar {} ;
```

It is taking ***forever***, and then some.  Yes, there are millions of files in the target directory.  (Each file is a measly 8 bytes in a well hashed directory structure.)  But just running...

```
find data/ -name filepattern-*2009* -print > filesOfInterest.txt
```

...takes only two hours or so.  At the rate my job is running, it won't be finished for a couple of *weeks*..  That seems unreasonable. **Is there a more efficient to do this?**  Maybe with a more complicated bash script?

A secondary questions is *"why is my current approach so slow?"*

Comment: The exec parameter spawns a new tar process for every file found. Additionally the tar update operation is expensive.

Comment: how many files do you have and how big are they? impact of invoking tar for each of the files makes a big difference for 10 petabyte files or 10 billion small files

Comment: @sfussenegger: 8 bytes each...have updated question.  As stated in q, there are *millions* of files.

Comment: @theomega, @Stu Thompson: that is exactly why there is a second variant of the `-exec`, with a `+` instead of a `;`. To be precise: `find data/ -name 'filepattern-*2009*' -exec tar uf 2009.tar '{}' +`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you already did the second command that created the file list, just use the `-T` option to tell tar to read the files names from that saved file list.  Running 1 tar command vs N tar commands will be a lot better.

Comment: After running with `xargs` for a while, I tried this approach...and it was **much** faster!

Comment: be careful with `xargs` in this situation: if there are many file names passed to it, it executes `tar` multiple times on subsets of the file list. In your case, with `tar -u` that probably works, but if you're creating a tar file `tar -c`, only the last subset of files will be in there once it's finished...

Answer (score 26):

One option is to use **cpio** to generate a tar-format archive:

```
$ find data/ -name "filepattern-*2009*" | cpio -ov --format=ustar > 2009.tar
```

**cpio** works natively with a list of filenames from stdin, rather than a top-level directory, which makes it an ideal tool for this situation.

Comment: this is an elegant solution. and you can run it over a network. replace `> 2009.tar` with `| ssh host tar xf -`

Comment: `find data/ -print0 | tar -T - --null --create -f archive.tar` reads the list of files from stdout, and uses null file delimiter

Comment: My ubuntu tar doesn't like having `--null` after `-T`.  I had to use: 

`find data/ -print0 | tar --null -T - --create -f archive.tar`

Comment: Beware: the cpio archive formats, like tar, do have maximum file name lengths.  The purported maximum length is 256; However, I have had it fail with a "file name too long" error message when processing a file whose name was 101 characters long.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a find-tar combination that can do what you want without the use of xargs or exec (which should result in a noticeable speed-up):

```
tar --version    # tar (GNU tar) 1.14 

# FreeBSD find (on Mac OS X)
find -x data -name "filepattern-*2009*" -print0 | tar --null --no-recursion -uf 2009.tar --files-from -

# for GNU find use -xdev instead of -x
gfind data -xdev -name "filepattern-*2009*" -print0 | tar --null --no-recursion -uf 2009.tar --files-from -

# added: set permissions via tar
find -x data -name "filepattern-*2009*" -print0 | \
    tar --null --no-recursion --owner=... --group=... --mode=... -uf 2009.tar --files-from -
```

Answer (score 7):

There is xargs for this:

```
find data/ -name filepattern-*2009* -print0 | xargs -0 tar uf 2009.tar
```

Guessing why it is slow is hard as there is not much information. What is the structure of the directory, what filesystem do you use, how it was configured on creating. Having milions of files in single directory is quite hard situation for most filesystems.

Comment: The directory is hashed nicely.  ext3, btw.  As I mentioned, the find command alone runs quickly so I believe the file system, the directory structure, etc is not an issue.

Comment: I think you'll have to add `--max-args=n` (short `-n n`) where `n` is the maximum number of arguments tar (or any other program) can take. `getconf ARG_MAX` should show how high this limit is (131,072 on my machine). It's possible though that xargs takes care of this itself.

Comment: Wow!  So I ran another command with `xargs` like you said 15 minutes ago, and the resulting tar file is already 25% of the size of my original command.  Thanks.

Comment: @Stu no "arg list too long" error? if no, I would have been overcautious ... once again :)

Comment: @Stu Hey, it's me again :) You could simply replace the `;` in your original command with a `+` to get the exact same effect. Just see the corresponding man page entry on -exec

Comment: @sfussenegger No errors (yet.)  273,838 files `tar`'d and counting.  RHEL4 64-bit.  `getconf ARG_MAX` reports 131k like you.

Comment: @Stu it would have failed immediately anyway. For instance, this happens when you do `tar -uf 2009.tar filepattern-*2009*` in a directory with 132k+ files.

Comment: xargs knows what is maximal number of args to pass, it is it's purpose, you need --max-args only if you want to pass less

Comment: Turns out that, while `xargs` is faster than my first approach, running tar with an input list via `-T` is much, much faster than both.

Answer (score 3):

To correctly handle file names with weird (but legal) characters (such as newlines, ...) you should write your file list to filesOfInterest.txt using find's -print0:

```
find -x data -name "filepattern-*2009*" -print0 > filesOfInterest.txt
tar --null --no-recursion -uf 2009.tar --files-from filesOfInterest.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you currently have things, you are invoking the tar command every single time it finds a file, which is not surprisingly slow. Instead of taking the two hours to print plus the amount of time it takes to open the tar archive, see if the files are out of date, and add them to the archive, you are actually multiplying those times together. You might have better success invoking the tar command once, after you have batched together all the names, possibly using xargs to achieve the invocation. By the way, I hope you are using 'filepattern-*2009*' and not filepattern-*2009* as the stars will be expanded by the shell without quotes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility for this called `tarsplitter`.

```
tarsplitter -m archive -i folder/*.json -o archive.tar -p 8
```

will use 8 threads to archive the files matching "folder/*.json" into an output archive of "archive.tar"

https://github.com/AQUAOSOTech/tarsplitter

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with linux for a long time before I found a much easier and potentially faster solution using Python's tarfile library.

1. Use glob.glob to search for the desired filepaths
2. Create a new archive in append mode
3. Add each filepath to this archive
4. Close the archive

Here is my code sample:

```
import tarfile
import glob
from tqdm import tqdm

filepaths = glob.glob("Images/7 *.jpeg")
n = len(filepaths)
print ("{} files found.".format(n))
print ("Creating Archive...")
out = tarfile.open("Images.tar.gz", mode = "a")
for filepath in tqdm(filepaths, "Appending files to the archive..."):
  try:
    out.add(filepath)
  except:
    print ("Failed to add: {}".format(filepath))

print ("Closing the archive...")
out.close()
```

This took a total of about 12 seconds to find 16222 filepaths and create the archive, however, this was predominantly taken up by simply searching for the filepaths. It took just 7 seconds to create the tar archive with 16000 filepaths. With some multithreading this could be much faster.

If you're looking for a multithreaded implementation, I've made one and placed it here:

```
import tarfile
import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
import threading

filepaths = glob.glob("Images/7 *.jpeg")
n = len(filepaths)
print ("{} files found.".format(n))
print ("Creating Archive...")
out = tarfile.open("Images.tar.gz", mode = "a")

def add(filepath):
  try:
    out.add(filepath)
  except:
    print ("Failed to add: {}".format(filepath))

def add_multiple(filepaths):
  for filepath in filepaths:
    add(filepath)

max_threads = 16
filepaths_per_thread = 16

interval = max_threads * filepaths_per_thread

for i in tqdm(range(0, n, interval), "Appending files to the archive..."):
  threads = [threading.Thread(target = add_multiple, args = (filepaths[j:j + filepaths_per_thread],)) for j in range(i, min([n, i + interval]), filepaths_per_thread)]
  for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
  for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print ("Closing the archive...")
out.close()
```

Of course, you need to make sure that the values of `max_threads` and `filepaths_per_thread` are optimized; it takes time to create threads, so the time may actually *increase* for certain values. A final thing to note is that since we are using append mode, we are automatically creating a new archive with the designated name if one does not already exist. However, if one *does* already exist, it will simply add to the preexisting archive, not reset it or make a new one.

Comment: Given that the OP question is now ten years old, I wonder how much impact SSDs would have had on the original time taken for the task. Something that should be considered when comparing old problems with new solutions, lest we be comparing apples with oranges.

Answer (score -2):

Simplest (also remove file after archive creation):

```
find *.1  -exec tar czf '{}.tgz' '{}' --remove-files \;
```

Comment: There is hardly any difference to the asker's original approach, which reportedly was too slow. Also, it unnecessarily removes the source files, which has not been asked for and will most certainly be undesireable.