# Find files (print in list file) tar this list, check archive and delete sources

Tags: bash, find, compare, tar, delete-file

I try to write a script to search specific paths for files older than a given time. Because of argument list length I do this not directly, but write found files to a list. In the second step I take this list and tar those files, the plan is to later read the tar listing and delete the files archived in source directories.

Find specific files and write list:
**Solution: added  -type f**

```
find /path/to/*/xfiles/* -type f -mtime +8 -print > /tmp/archiv-xfiles.manifest
```

this is working correct as far as I can see. File list is different with each run, while this will be an effect of using mtime which is working relative I guess. Now I take the list and tar the files listed:

```
tar -czvPf /tmp/archiv-xfiles.tar.gz --files-from /tmp/archiv-xfiles.manifest
```

At this Point I'm stuck with an archive containing each file three times? The printed manifest list is correct, each file only appearing once. Am I evil?

While I would go on like that:

```
tar -tvf /tmp/archiv-xfiles.tar.gz > /tmp/archiv-xfiles-to-delete.manifest
```

**Do I Need an error check here too to be sure of non-corrupted Archive?**

```
diff /tmp/archiv-xfiles.manifest /tmp/archiv-xfiles-to-delete.manifest > /dev/null
v1=$?
if [ $v1 == 0 ] ; then
```

Now I see two ways to go on, first one. **Which one is faster?:**

```
cat /tmp/archiv-xfiles-to-delete.manifest | xargs rm -rf
```

or second:

```
while read line
do
rm -f $line        
done < /tmp/archiv-xfiles-to-delete.manifest
```

Do not know which one is better? Guess using `tar --remove-files` switch is no good or save idea?
And the rest:

```
rm -f /tmp/archiv-xfiles.manifest
rm -f /tmp/archiv-xfiles-to-delete.manifest
elif
echo ERROR, check manifest files! | mail -s ScriptError someone@somewhere.com
fi
```

Maybe someone can tell me what going wrong with tarring the list, while any ideas on the whole script are really appreciated. For example, is the tar option "--remove-files" a save and reliable way to achieve the same effect as my way of listing the tar content, diff and delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As for tarring the list: you are probably getting additional codes because your list have both files and containing dirs. Try adding '-type f' to the find incantation to get only files.

2) As for argument list length, one of the points of using xargs is exactly that it take care of it; you could just do

```
find ..... -print0 | xargs rm
```

3) I really fail to see why you would want to generate a list, tar the files and regenerate the same list again from the tar archive.

Comment: 1) Yesss this did help, good thought, while i do not see why leaving out this switch results in tripple files instead of double?   2) i did use xargs, but was stuck with incomplete archives because tar does abnormal behaviour with more than 30 000 files.   3) because mtime does work relative to the second it is called, it would delete more files by second call than that have been archived with the first call some time before. because files are very important for documentation i am moreover wondering if listing archive file is test enough to be shure of non corrupt archive?

Comment: 1) Probably matching file, dir and parent dir ;). 2) The tar archives should not have problem with 30000 files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697213/more-efficient-way-to-find-tar-millions-of-files for a user with millions. 3) I see. So the tar file isn't just a by-product, it's useful. 4) What about -W tar option (http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/verify.html)

Comment: 1) i guess so 2) i ended up with /bin/tar: Argument list too Long 3) i thought of it but verify needs to work from root while i work from other dir (or better dir independed in script) and somehow i like the diff way :)